# Selenium + Python: NoAlertPresentException and TimeoutException when trying to get text from a pop up alert not visible in HTML

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests

Currently, I'm using Selenium + Python to test contact form fields of a website. I have a test case that's testing for an unhappy path, more precisely, it tests for an error message that appears when  the text in one of the input fields is in a wrong format.

The error message is a pop up alert not visible as an HTML element (I've attached an image of it). What I want my script to do is to get the text of that error message and make an assertion. However, nothing I've tried works. I've even checked different posts on Stack Overflow, and unfortunately, I don't see that any of them are closely related to my problem.

[Pop up alert error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwd27.png)

URL of contact form fields of the tested website: https://ovdjeisada.hr/kontakt/

The scenario is as follows: after clicking the 'Submit' button, the aforementioned pop up alert error message appears.

1. This is the code that gives me `NoAlertPresentException`:

```
# Switch driver to the alert dialog
alert = driver.switch_to.alert
alert_text = alert.text
# Verify that "Please, match the format requested. Only numbers allowed. Minimum length: 8 characters" error
# message is displayed
confirmation_message = "Please, match the format requested. Only numbers allowed. Minimum length: 8 characters"
assert alert_text == confirmation_message, "Wrong confirmation message"
print("Correct error message is displayed")
```

It breaks on `alert = driver.switch_to.alert`.

2. This is the code that gives me `TimeoutException`:

```
# Switch driver to the alert dialog
wait.until(ec.alert_is_present())
alert = driver.switch_to.alert
alert_text = alert.text
# Verify that "Please, match the format requested. Only numbers allowed. Minimum length: 8 characters" error
# message is displayed
confirmation_message = "Please, match the format requested. Only numbers allowed. Minimum length: 8 characters"
assert alert_text == confirmation_message, "Wrong confirmation message"
print("Correct error message is displayed")
```

It breaks on `wait.until(ec.alert_is_present())`.

Comment: it would be better if you could provide the URL so that others can reproduce the issue and fix it.

Comment: Great idea! Thanks! Here it is: https://ovdjeisada.hr/kontakt/
I've added the link in the post also.